# Access violation on run function from dll

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have DLL, interface on C++ for work with he. In bcb, msvc it works fine. I want to use Python-scripts to access function in this library.
Generate python-package using Swig.

File *setup.py*

```
 import distutils
 from distutils.core import setup, Extension

 setup(name = "DCM",
     version = "1.3.2",
     ext_modules = [Extension("_dcm", ["dcm.i"], swig_opts=["-c++","-D__stdcall"])],
     y_modules = ['dcm'])
```

file *dcm.i*

```
%module dcm
%include <windows.i>

%{
#include <windows.h>
#include "../interface/DcmInterface.h"
#include "../interface/DcmFactory.h"
#include "../interface/DcmEnumerations.h"
%}

%include "../interface/DcmEnumerations.h"
%include "../interface/DcmInterface.h"
%include "../interface/DcmFactory.h"
```

run these command (python is associated with extension .py)

```
setup build
setup install
```

using this DLL

```
import dcm

f = dcm.Factory() #ok

r = f.getRegistrationMessage() #ok
print "r.GetLength() ", r.GetLength() #ok
r.SetLength(0) #access violation
```

On last string I get access violation. And I have  access violation on every function using input parameters.

*DcmInterface.h* (interface)

```
class IRegistrationMessage
{
public:
...
    virtual int GetLength() const = 0;
    virtual void SetLength(int value) = 0;
...
};
```

*uRegistrationMessage.cpp* (implementation in DLL)

```
class TRegistrationMessage : public IRegistrationMessage
{
public:
...
virtual int GetLength() const
    {
        return FLength;
    }
    virtual void SetLength(int Value)
    {
        FLength = Value;
        FLengthExists = true;
    }
...
};
```

Factory

*DcmFactory.h* (using DLL in client code)

```
class Factory
{
private:
    GetRegistrationMessageFnc GetRegistration;

bool loadLibrary(const char *dllFileName = "dcmDLL.dll" )
    {
    ...
        hDLL = LoadLibrary(dllFileName);
        if (!hDLL) return false;
        ...
        GetRegistration = (GetRegistrationMessageFnc) GetProcAddress( hDLL, "getRegistration" );
        ...
    }
public:
Factory(const char* dllFileName = "dcmDLL.dll")
{
    loadLibrary(dllFileName);
}

IRegistrationMessage* getRegistrationMessage()
    {
        if(!GetRegistration) return 0;
        return GetRegistration();
    };
};
```

Comment: Maybe you could add the line that calls `Factory::SetLength()` from the generated code and the original declaration from `DcmFactory.h`?

Comment: ...
arg1 = reinterpret_cast< DataCollector::IRegistrationMessage * >(argp1);
  ecode2 = SWIG_AsVal_int(obj1, &val2);
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(ecode2)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(ecode2), "in method '" "IRegistrationMessage_SetLength" "', argument " "2"" of type '" "int""'");
  } 
  arg2 = static_cast< int >(val2);
  (arg1)->SetLength(arg2);
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find bug.
If you using DLL, you must write calling conventions in an explicit form like this:

```
class IRegistrationMessage
{
public:
...
    virtual int _cdecl GetLength() const = 0;
    virtual void _cdecl SetLength(int value) = 0;
...
};
```

I append calling conventions and now all work fine.